# In right triangle PQR, ∠Q = $90 ^\circ$ and PR = 2PQ, then ∠R is equal to?

Tags: trigonometry

This one comes from my module without proper explanation.Please suggest how to approach this problem ?

PS:How do you write degree (in symbol) in math-mode ?

Comment: Hint: Do you know where the mathematical functions $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$ come from?

Comment: Usually you use "^\circ" for degree symbol in LaTex.

Comment: A trig-less hint: Make a copy of $PQR$ and paste the two triangles together "back to back" along their $QR$ sides. What's special about the bigger triangle formed this way?

Comment: @ Day Late Don : Interesting but I didn't understand what you meant here ?

Comment: @Debanjan: Let $P'$ be the mirror image of $P$ across the segment $QR$. The triangle $P'QR$ is the copy that is pasted "back to back" with $PQR$ along $QR$. Since $P'Q$ and $PQ$ are both perpendicular to $QR$, the two segments together form a larger segment $PP'$ of the triangle $PP'R$. Since $PR=2PQ$, we know that $P'R=2PQ$. Now, observe that $PP'=...$, so ... (I'm simply walking through the traditional construction used to determine sines and cosines of two fundamental angles, but avoiding the trigonometric terminology, which isn't needed here, and which may be unfamiliar to the Questioner.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Djaian pointed out use the fact that $$\sin\angle{R} = \frac{PQ}{PR}=\frac{PQ}{2PQ}=\frac{1}{2}$$ So $\angle{R} = ?$

Also i hope you are aware of the fact that in a right angled triangle $$\sin\theta =\frac{\text{Opposite Side}}{\text{Hypotenuse}}$$